# not able to call python file output using angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs.
I am working on a code where depending on the output of the python file, the angularjs file should react differently.
I keep getting this particular error

```
angular.js:10765 GET http://harsha.seq-technology.in/ajax/duplicate_check.py?q=0 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

what am i doing wrong ?
my script file is as below:

```
$scope.save_me = function () {
   $scope.dup_yes=1;
   console.log("here");
   $http.get("/ajax/duplicate_check.py",{params{"q":0}}).then(function(response) {
       console.log("here2");
       console.log(response.data);

       if (response.data['login_status'] == 1 ){
          console.log("Mission is a Success\n");
       }
    })
}
```

my python file gives the output as follows:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{"login_status": 1}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with angularjs, first be sure you make your "script" return a proper HTTP response with a 200 result code.

You can `curl` or `wget` to debug the result before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

my python file wasn't executable, hence the error.
had to change file permissions.
thanks!